# ffmpeg SDP file for Darwin Streaming Server

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, darwin, sdp, ffserver

I am making a streaming server to view live video feed of my webcam on my mobile device.

I considered using ffmpeg , VLC and DSS and made the following setup that worked somewhat, though the frames were skipped :-

video4linux2       > ffserver              > VLC transcoding        > DSS

(RAW to ffserver)  > (outputs to SDP link) > (SDP link to SDP file) > (SDP file to live streaming to mobile)

Later, on testing VLC i found to be very inefficient and slow on my Netbook(Intel Atom N480) as it skips lot of frames.

DSS can stream a SDP file from its /usr/local/movies(default).

And at the same time, ffmpeg's ffserver module can stream live feed to SDP link(not SDP file).

My requirement is that i need to create SDP file in DSS's /usr/local/movies directory so as to pass this DSS for streaming.

So, how to create a sdp file from ffmpeg or how to create SDP file from SDP link (without using VLC's trans-coding).

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the wirecast for getting your video from source(cam) and then push it to DSS on the sdp that will do the same thing which you want to do

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention but i'm making server on Linux System. Wirecast is only for mac and windows.